# Getting 403 error with {"error":"unknown_error"} message while creating keycloak user

Tags: keycloak

I'm getting error while creating user to keycloak. Please find the details below,

Postman : http://localhost:8180/auth/admin/realms/one-app/users

Headers: Authorization = Bearer <access_toke>

Body : {
"username":"test123",
"email":"test@test.com",
"emailVerified":true,
"enabled":true,
"firstName":"Test",
"lastName":"123",
"realmRoles":["app-user"],
"credentials":[{
"value":"test123",
"temporary":false,
"type": "password"
}]
}

But I'm getting error like below. Here I'm attaching my postman details as images.

[Response Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z2PEj.png)`,`
[Request Body](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3bcl1.png)`,`
[Request Headers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a578v.png)`,`
[Access Token API](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mQ6WS.png)

Comment: You got a 403 (Forbidden). Did you grant the necessary permissions (eg user management) to your user ?

Comment: Thanks @TacheDeChoco, after assigning the permission it is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

After Adding the manage_user permission to my app admin user. It is started working.

Thank you